# Arcpy Copy_management does not copy all records

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I need some help with a python script that is copying a shapefile to a new folder location. I am using ArcGIS 10.3. I have a shapefile of imagery tile outlines that contains 17425 polygons. I need to make a copy of the shapefile in a new folder location. I am using arcpy.Copy_management() to copy the shapefile into the new location.  After I run the script the copied shapefile only contains 2826 of the original records. Some how I am losing tiles during the copy. If I run the tool manually from inside a map session, all the records copy over completely. I think the problem might be my shapefile and not the script, but have a look. Here is my script:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = "C:/Documents/Working"

# Set local variables
in_data =  "Imagery_Tiles.shp"
out_data = "C:/Documents/Tiles/Tile_Shapes.shp"
data_type = ""

# Execute Copy
arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data, data_type)
```

Comment: DO you have an active selection set on the layer?

Comment: thanks @Vince, no I do not have any features selected before I do the copy. I thought that might be the problem too, but I have Arcmap closed and I am running just the script you see in the post.

Comment: Since it is just a .shp could you use CopyFeatures_management instead?

Comment: Just an idea try importing the shape file into a file geodatabase just to see if they all go into it, then if you need it to be a shapefile, export out again?

Comment: Environment Extent plays tricks sometime

Comment: That's a great idea @Hornbydd, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured out the issue. My shapefile had NULL geometries. I ran the Repair Geometry tool with the 'Delete NULL geometries' option checked to see if there were any problems with my shapefile. The result from the repair left me with 2826 records, the exact amount that were left over from the Copy Management tool.

I had to create a new shapefile, this time with no geometry problems. I ran the script again and it runs fine now that I have a proper shapefile.